# Adding signature for mail, not displaying properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I need to add an signature at the end of the body, heres what I have tried so far.

```
 msg.Body = (fk.Status + "\n \n \n \n Best Regards \n" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() );
```

where `msg` is:

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage()
```

But the newline isn't working. The mail is sending fine and everything, but it all comes in a one liner.

Is there a better way to add signature? or a way to manipulate the text?

Comment: Use system.environment.newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your email is Html use `<br/>`:

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true; // You need this to render mail as html
msg.Body = (fk.Status + @"<br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> Best Regards <br/>" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() );
```

Comment: mhh i have been trying your solution, but no text appears in the email, should i put some other html tags for text to appear?

Comment: i got it to work, using the <p> tag thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of \n use

```
system.environment.newline
```

Or use /r/n